# Bootstrap 5 OffCanvas not working inside navbar with sm screen

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

I'm trying to get Bootstrap 5 OffCanvas working inside Navbar but it's not working except on mobile screen size of `sm` or lower. I need to show the hamburger menu in `sm` screen size and so there's nothing I could do there.

How do I make this work on a laptop/desktop?

**JSFIddle Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/emzrf80v/**

HTML:

```
<header class="menu">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm">
            <div class="container">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
                    <img src="" class="logo">
                </a>
                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarCollapse" aria-controls="navbarCollapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarCollapse">
                    hey
                </div>
                <div class="d-flex"><span class="icon icon-search"></span></div>
                <div class="offcanvas offcanvas-top" id="demo">
                    <div class="offcanvas-header">
                        <h1 class="offcanvas-title">Heading</h1>
                        <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="offcanvas"></button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="offcanvas-body">
                        <p>Some text lorem ipsum.</p>
                        <p>Some text lorem ipsum.</p>
                        <p>Some text lorem ipsum.</p>
                        <button class="btn btn-secondary" type="button">A Button</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="container-fluid mt-3">
                    <h3>Offcanvas Sidebar</h3>
                    <p>Offcanvas is similar to modals, except that it is often used as a sidebar.</p>
                    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-bs-toggle="offcanvas" data-bs-target="#demo">
                        Open Offcanvas Sidebar
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </header>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the "navbar-expand-sm" class from the nav tag.
You can also adjust it as per other breakpoints like "navbar-expand-md" or "navbar-expand-lg".

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-Zenh87qX5JnK2Jl0vWa8Ck2rdkQ2Bzep5IDxbcnCeuOxjzrPF/et3URy9Bv1WTRi" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-OERcA2EqjJCMA+/3y+gxIOqMEjwtxJY7qPCqsdltbNJuaOe923+mo//f6V8Qbsw3" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<header class="menu">
    <nav class="navbar">
        <div class="container">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
                <img src="" class="logo">
            </a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarCollapse" aria-controls="navbarCollapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarCollapse">
                hey
            </div>
            <div class="d-flex"><span class="icon icon-search"></span></div>
            <div class="offcanvas offcanvas-top" id="demo">
                <div class="offcanvas-header">
                    <h1 class="offcanvas-title">Heading</h1>
                    <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="offcanvas"></button>
                </div>
                <div class="offcanvas-body">
                    <p>Some text lorem ipsum.</p>
                    <p>Some text lorem ipsum.</p>
                    <p>Some text lorem ipsum.</p>
                    <button class="btn btn-secondary" type="button">A Button</button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="container-fluid mt-3">
                <h3>Offcanvas Sidebar</h3>
                <p>Offcanvas is similar to modals, except that it is often used as a sidebar.</p>
                <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-bs-toggle="offcanvas" data-bs-target="#demo">
                    Open Offcanvas Sidebar
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
</header>
```

Comment: That's not a solution as the mobile hamburger will not show in mobile screen if I remove that class. i need the hamburger menu.

Comment: No. It will show on all screens. Please try and check.